# Add probability of x and conversion %

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

This is how the data currently looks like:

```
id testers_time stage_1_to_2_time activated_time stage_2_to_3_time engaged_time
a  10           30                40             30                70
b  30               
c  15           30                45        
d       

dict = {'id': ['a','b','c','d'], 'testers_time': [10, 30, 15, None], 'stage_1_to_2_time': [30, None, 30, None], 'activated_time' : [40, None, 45, None],'stage_2_to_3_time' : [30, None, None, None],'engaged_time' : [70, None, None, None]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=['id', 'testers_time', 'stage_1_to_2_time', 'activated_time', 'stage_2_to_3_time', 'engaged_time'])
```

I have a plot of `testers_time` against its cumulative probability from a CDF:

```
def ecdf(df):
    n = len(df)
    x = np.sort(df)
    y = np.arange(1.0, n+1) / n
    return x, y

df = df['testers_time'].dropna().sort_values()
print(df)

x, y = ecdf(df)

plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='none') 

plt.axvline(x.mean(), color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2) #Add mean 

x_m = int(x.mean()) 
y_m = stats.percentileofscore(df, x.mean())/100.0 

plt.annotate('(%s,%s)' % (x_m,int(y_m*100)) , xy=(x_m,y_m), xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points') 

percentiles= np.array([0,25,50,75,100]) 
x_p = np.percentile(df, percentiles) 
y_p = percentiles/100.0 

plt.plot(x_p, y_p, marker='D', color='red', linestyle='none') # Overlay quartiles 

for x,y in zip(x_p, y_p): 
    plt.annotate('%s' % int(x), xy=(x,y), xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')
```

What I am trying to do is graph `testers_time` against:

1) Its none-cumulative probability, if graphed it should look like a sort of a PDF

2) Its cumulative conversion %, where conversion is any `id` that has a populated (not blank or null) `testers_time`. So id `a` (1 of 4 ids) converts, that's 25%, id `b` converts, thats 50% (since cumulative), id `c` converts, that's 75%, and id `d` doesnt convert so 75% conversion is the max, at 30 days `testers_time`.

Can you assist with adding the above into columns in the `df`, or graph them? Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure `ecdf(df)` does not work as intended. For example you assign to `df['x']`, then return `x`. Also I think it would help if you have provided [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (your `df` seems to have irrelevant columns) and expected output. It is unclear for me what do you mean by "max being the 75% conversion at 30 days".

Comment: @abukaj I edited the code, please run it as is. I also provided an explanation to your question. Really appreciate the help. Still have 21 hours to aware the bounty if that's helpful in any way in terms of incentive :)

Comment: Take a look at `.rank()` method of `Series` object.

Comment: @abukaj so along the lines of: `df['rank'] = df['testers_time'].rank(ascending=1)/len(df)` for conversion. I think I can work with that, thank you. What about Q1?

Comment: I'd try `numpy.unique()`, it has count option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1: `df['prob'] = df['testers_time'].map(df.testers_time.value_counts(normalize=True))`

A2: `df['conv'] = df['testers_time'].rank(ascending=1)/len(df)`